# How can you calculate the frequencies of elements across multiple columns?

Tags: r, frequency, frequency-distribution

I was wondering about the most efficient way to calculate the frequencies of repeated values across multiple columns. In the code example below, I want to calculate the total number of times each unique value (1, 2, or 3) appears across the 3 columns (x, y, z). Thanks for your help!

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(2,3,1)
z <- c(3,2,2)

df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

I'm new to R. So I tried using table() but it's not giving me what I'm looking for (the total number of times each unique value appears across the 3 columns).

Comment: `table(unlist(df))` ?

Comment: Awesome thanks @akrun ! Missed the unlist()

Comment: Sir kindly see this follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74381726/store-frequency-from-unlist-in-a-dataframe)